# vimscript for Ultisnips+Deoplete compatibility

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm wondering how to write a function that overloads `<TAB>`.

First it would do a check to see if there is a snippet that needs to be completed,  and if there is a snippet, then expand it.

Otherwise, I would like the function to do a check to see if there is a space before the cursor (or we are on new line) before Tab is pressed. If so, then it should do regular `<tab>`. 
Otherwise, I'd like for it to call

```
deoplete#manual_complete()
```

Unless there is already a menu open, in which case, I should be able to tab through it.

Here was my attempt (Which fails completely) and some settings for reference:

```
let g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res = 0 "default value, just set once

function! Ulti_ExpandOrJump_and_getRes()
  call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()
  return g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res
endfunction

inoremap <silent><expr> <tab>
  \ (Ulti_ExpandOrJump_and_getRes() > 0) ? "\<C-y>"
  \ : pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" :
  \ <SID>check_back_space() ? "\<TAB>" :
  \ deoplete#manual_complete()

function! s:check_back_space() abort "{{{
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1] =~ '\s'
endfunction "}}}
```

Oddly enough, when I press tab, the bottom right of vim reads that I have typed   "^I", which is very strange behavior.

The reason I do not have the ultisnips expand trigger as "tab" is that it disables the use of tab for deoplete (for whatever reason.)

Comment: part of the script I have was nabbed to get the tab to work normally with deoplete from a github issue

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi & Vim StackExchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim and Vimscript!

Comment: @filbranden I didn't even know that existed! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the main issue you're running into is that `UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()` will try to move the cursor and that's a problem from an `<expr>` mapping in insert mode. Using `<C-R>=...<CR>` instead should make it work. (At least that's what the example in UltiSnips documentation uses.)

I'd also recommend using a single function to handle all Tab cases instead of a rather long one-liner. That way you can use `if`s and document each case specifically.

I also think for the case you expand or jump on UltiSnips, you want to expand to nothing rather than a `<C-y>`, right?

Putting it all together:

```
function! HandleTab() abort
  " First, try to expand or jump on UltiSnips.
  call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()
  if g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res > 0
    return ""
  endif
  " Then, check if we're in a completion menu
  if pumvisible()
    return "\<C-n>"
  endif
  " Then check if we're indenting.
  let col = col('.') - 1
  if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] =~ '\s'
    return "\<Tab>"
  endif
  " Finally, trigger deoplete completion.
  return deoplete#manual_complete()
endfunction

inoremap <silent> <Tab> <C-R>=HandleTab()<CR>
```

You might want to review the order of the checks. It seems to me that checking for `pumvisible()` should be first. Also, checking whether you're indenting is probably cheaper than checking for an UltiSnips expansion, though I guess you could be jumping through fields when you have a space... Anyways, it should be easy to tweak this to make it work.

Comment: wow this is almost a perfect solution. And actually it is perfect for the question stated above. unfortunately, I  now have the issue that when I want to  autocomplete (with deoplete) the cursor jumps before! Is there any way to have it ultisnips#expand but not jump, and then only jump if plum is not visible?

Comment: I've accepted the answer, since it did completely answer the question as stated.

Comment: @AndresMejia Glad this helped! You might be able to use `UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()` to check if you can expand only, and perhaps `UltiSnips#JumpForwards()` to check if you can jump. There are global variables to check whether these succeeded or not. See `:help UltiSnips-trigger-functions` for more details. (Not sure if that helps... Do I understand correctly that you want to jump only if not performing completion, is that correct?) Hopefully this will get you in the right direction.